# R Graph missing title using moving averages "ts_ma" function from "TSstudio" library

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, moving-average

The title that I have created does not come up. Instead it comes up with the variable name in the code "Naypyitaw.xts" at the top of the graph.

How do I get the title on the graph and the X and Y axis to be labeled as the Y and X axis do not appear as well?

```
library(TSstudio)

# A one-side moving average order of 7
MA <- ts_ma(Naypyitaw.xts, n_left = 6, n = NULL,
                   title = "Weekly Moving Average For Naypyitaw", 
                   Ytitle = "Gross Income",
                   Xtitle  = "Date",
                   show_legend = TRUE)
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

My Naypyitaw.xts file-

```
                [,1]
2019-01-01  388.2900
2019-01-01  132.7620
2019-01-01  132.0270
2019-01-01  184.0860
2019-01-02  209.6220
2019-01-02  266.0280
2019-01-03   44.3520
2019-01-03   79.6740
2019-01-04  629.8425
2019-01-05  172.4940
2019-01-05   33.4950
2019-01-05  239.5890
2019-01-05  579.8415
2019-01-06  939.5400
2019-01-06  343.0560
2019-01-07   71.5260
2019-01-07  229.1100
2019-01-07   85.7430
2019-01-08  299.8485
2019-01-08  575.7360
2019-01-08  190.5960
2019-01-08   13.4190
2019-01-08  381.3915
2019-01-08  175.0455
2019-01-08  688.7160
2019-01-08   76.5765
2019-01-09  463.4280
2019-01-09 1002.1200
2019-01-09  310.7160
2019-01-09  165.9000
2019-01-09  708.3195
2019-01-10  392.6475
2019-01-10  611.0790
2019-01-10  477.1305
2019-01-11  183.0360
2019-01-11  270.2595
2019-01-12  419.8320
2019-01-12 1023.7500
2019-01-13  437.3250
2019-01-13   78.0045
2019-01-13   88.3680
2019-01-14  451.3635
2019-01-14  133.4340
2019-01-14   89.0715
2019-01-14  190.4805
2019-01-14  390.9465
2019-01-14  423.7380
2019-01-15   91.5600
2019-01-15  597.0405
2019-01-15  586.6350
2019-01-16 1003.5900
2019-01-16  881.3070
2019-01-16   32.5290
2019-01-16  125.9790
2019-01-16  497.0700
2019-01-17  377.5800
2019-01-17  137.8650
2019-01-17  131.9220
2019-01-18   41.3910
2019-01-18  856.4535
2019-01-18  446.4390
2019-01-19  362.7120
2019-01-19   93.0405
2019-01-19   84.9765
2019-01-19  235.7460
2019-01-19  250.2780
2019-01-20  749.7000
2019-01-20  348.3060
2019-01-20  131.2080
2019-01-20  470.9880
2019-01-21  624.8970
2019-01-21   72.4290
2019-01-22  106.9950
2019-01-22   85.5855
2019-01-22  206.7975
2019-01-23  161.7000
2019-01-23  198.9960
2019-01-23  942.9000
2019-01-23  323.1480
2019-01-23  264.7575
2019-01-23  527.7510
2019-01-23   87.2340
2019-01-23   57.6975
2019-01-23  333.9840
2019-01-23  734.7060
2019-01-24   63.9135
2019-01-24  270.0180
2019-01-25   16.2015
2019-01-25  950.2500
2019-01-25  288.2040
2019-01-25  663.2955
2019-01-25  267.3405
2019-01-26  471.0300
2019-01-26  193.4625
2019-01-26   68.2395
2019-01-26  106.5015
2019-01-27  150.7800
2019-01-27  510.9615
2019-01-27  488.9850
2019-01-27  568.5120
2019-01-27  145.7400
2019-01-27  178.1640
2019-01-28  680.1480
2019-01-28  273.4200
2019-01-28  293.2020
2019-01-28   91.4025
2019-01-28  125.0550
2019-01-28  118.2510
2019-01-29  120.6450
2019-01-29  265.1040
2019-01-29  616.9800
2019-01-29   42.3675
2019-01-30  160.4400
2019-01-30  509.4075
2019-01-30   24.1080
2019-01-30 1034.4600
2019-01-30   55.2825
2019-01-30   23.4990
2019-01-31  155.6520
2019-01-31  224.4375
2019-01-31  829.0800
2019-01-31  652.8900
2019-02-01  218.0115
2019-02-01  763.4655
2019-02-01  551.1240
2019-02-02  117.8310
2019-02-02  400.7640
2019-02-02  554.1480
2019-02-02   40.3410
2019-02-02  223.5870
2019-02-02  175.0350
2019-02-03  671.7900
2019-02-03  212.7300
2019-02-03  310.5900
2019-02-03  517.9650
2019-02-04   14.6790
2019-02-04  130.8825
2019-02-05  309.3615
2019-02-05  720.3000
2019-02-05  145.5930
2019-02-05  297.8010
2019-02-06  417.5640
2019-02-06   94.2375
2019-02-06  407.3160
2019-02-06  239.4000
2019-02-06   55.0410
2019-02-06  188.0025
2019-02-07  103.8240
2019-02-07  276.9480
2019-02-07  343.2240
2019-02-07  122.5245
2019-02-07  273.7980
2019-02-07  618.9750
2019-02-07  507.4440
2019-02-07   10.6785
2019-02-07  180.8730
2019-02-08 1020.7050
2019-02-08  273.0525
2019-02-08  341.0925
2019-02-09   78.4350
2019-02-09  472.3110
2019-02-09   66.4020
2019-02-09   22.6590
2019-02-09  100.4850
2019-02-09  888.4050
2019-02-10   70.2870
2019-02-10  820.3650
2019-02-10  539.3430
2019-02-11  652.2600
2019-02-11  936.6000
2019-02-11  455.1225
2019-02-12  914.5500
2019-02-12   54.9675
2019-02-13  165.4485
2019-02-13  195.2580
2019-02-13   31.2270
2019-02-14  208.6770
2019-02-14  290.4300
2019-02-14  122.4720
2019-02-15   77.9310
2019-02-15 1042.6500
2019-02-15  253.5120
2019-02-15  103.7820
2019-02-15  344.4000
2019-02-15  282.5760
2019-02-15  287.9100
2019-02-16  718.7565
2019-02-16   63.2625
2019-02-16  300.5730
2019-02-17  374.7975
2019-02-17   62.0025
2019-02-17  440.9370
2019-02-17  499.7265
2019-02-18  284.1930
2019-02-18  185.0940
2019-02-18   63.9975
2019-02-19  173.2080
2019-02-19  733.6035
2019-02-19  183.1200
2019-02-19  603.8760
2019-02-20   90.5835
2019-02-21   13.1670
2019-02-21  207.4800
2019-02-21  439.2150
2019-02-22   31.9305
2019-02-22  701.8515
2019-02-22   26.7330
2019-02-23  337.5120
2019-02-23   37.6845
2019-02-23  429.1665
2019-02-24  772.3800
2019-02-24  351.0990
2019-02-24  259.7700
2019-02-24   53.3400
2019-02-25  451.7100
2019-02-25   51.0405
2019-02-26  216.6885
2019-02-27  793.5480
2019-02-27  104.6745
2019-02-27  631.1445
2019-02-28  722.2320
2019-02-28  195.7200
2019-03-01  742.2975
2019-03-01  314.5380
2019-03-02   85.1130
2019-03-02   30.2190
2019-03-02  572.7750
2019-03-02  543.7530
2019-03-02  485.5725
2019-03-02  629.1600
2019-03-03  860.6850
2019-03-03  175.1400
2019-03-03  272.5800
2019-03-03  293.1390
2019-03-03  369.6840
2019-03-03  253.6800
2019-03-04  829.0800
2019-03-04   31.7520
2019-03-05  822.2550
2019-03-05  610.4910
2019-03-05  232.1550
2019-03-05  127.2600
2019-03-05  480.0285
2019-03-06   38.8500
2019-03-07   69.0900
2019-03-07  209.5590
2019-03-07  353.0940
2019-03-07  139.9230
2019-03-08   80.2200
2019-03-08  512.1900
2019-03-08  291.4380
2019-03-08  394.2750
2019-03-08   90.8670
2019-03-08   71.5680
2019-03-09  478.2330
2019-03-09  256.7775
2019-03-09   17.0940
2019-03-09  935.2665
2019-03-10  144.0810
2019-03-10  860.4750
2019-03-10  338.2155
2019-03-11  254.0160
2019-03-11  218.0745
2019-03-11  294.6510
2019-03-12  192.8430
2019-03-12  174.3000
2019-03-12  395.8920
2019-03-12  194.1240
2019-03-12  404.5440
2019-03-13  536.8440
2019-03-13  153.0480
2019-03-13   59.3250
2019-03-13  102.3960
2019-03-14  148.9740
2019-03-14  204.6975
2019-03-14  484.9740
2019-03-14  441.6930
2019-03-14  625.9050
2019-03-14  814.3800
2019-03-14  461.5275
2019-03-14   44.9925
2019-03-14  221.8860
2019-03-15  548.1840
2019-03-16   32.2770
2019-03-16  829.7100
2019-03-16  408.4920
2019-03-17  369.4950
2019-03-17   23.7510
2019-03-18  299.5650
2019-03-18   54.0435
2019-03-18   96.5790
2019-03-19  867.6150
2019-03-19  277.7880
2019-03-19   55.8810
2019-03-19  937.8180
2019-03-19   48.5100
2019-03-19  743.8200
2019-03-19  317.2260
2019-03-20  745.3950
2019-03-20  523.9710
2019-03-20  132.5625
2019-03-21  360.9270
2019-03-23  461.3280
2019-03-23  596.8200
2019-03-23  408.7335
2019-03-23  495.3165
2019-03-24  321.1110
2019-03-24   78.6030
2019-03-24   77.1750
2019-03-24  681.9750
2019-03-24  329.1960
2019-03-25  627.6165
2019-03-25  401.7300
2019-03-25  248.4090
2019-03-26   51.1455
2019-03-26   91.7700
2019-03-26  154.1295
2019-03-26  176.9250
2019-03-27  943.2990
2019-03-28  150.0975
2019-03-28  121.5900
2019-03-28  209.1180
2019-03-29  121.1280
2019-03-29  864.5700
2019-03-30  609.1680
2019-03-30  442.3230
2019-03-30   85.5120
2019-03-30  304.9830
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example dataset with your code as well as the package that you are  using for this graph.